# filter_input_array -> FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT -> exept , and . in all INPUT_POST fields

Tags: php, arrays, definition, filter-input

The form have 6 fields, only numbers are allowed except , and .

Now I try to use filter_input_array to check. When I use

```
filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT);
```

the script change 0,5 to 05.

When I try it this way:

```
$filter = array('filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, 'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION);
$perf['post'] = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST, $filter);
```

perf['post'] looks like this:

> Array ([filter] => [flags] =>  )

So I have to make an entry for all form fields in my $filter array? Also when i just have one rule for all fields?

Answer (score 2):

You can't currently add the flags you need (`FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND | FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION`) to any of the filter array functions without specifying each field individually; although that *would* be nice.

### Alternative options:

#### Specify each field

```
$filter = array(
    'field_one' => array(
        'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,
        'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND | FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION
    ),
    'field_two' => array(
        'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,
        'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND | FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION
    ),
    ...
);
```

#### Reuse definition array

```
$my_number_def = array(
        'filter' => FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,
        'flags' => FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND | FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION
    );

$filter = array(
        'field_one' => $my_number_def,
        'field_two' => $my_number_def,
        ...
    );
```

#### Individually

```
$args = FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_THOUSAND | FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION;

$perf['post']['one'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'postOne', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, $args);
$perf['post']['two'] = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'postTwo', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, $args);
```

#### Manually

regex:

```
$perf['post'] = preg_grep('/^[0-9,.]$/', $_POST); // unverified regex!
```